# Sentence structure with "fitting"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> Wework’s building in Tokyo’s Shibuya district is a cross between an iceberg and a plastic bottle passed through a shredder. **Fitting, then, that the office-rental firm’s abortive listing, shelved on September 17th, threatens a financial shredding for its mastermind, Masayoshi Son—and that the debacle may be the tip of an iceberg for his $100bn Vision Fund (VF).**

I wonder about the structure of the second sentence in bold type. How can "fitting" be ahead of whole sentence alone?

Answer (score 3):

The subject and helping verb "it is" are implied in this sentence for emphasis on how the preceding sentence and this sentence are connected.

> [It is] fitting, then, that the office-rental firm's abortive listing [...] threatens a financial shredding for its mastermind[.]

Comment: Then is it possible to omit any subject and verb in case that they are implied in the following sentence?

Comment: I'd be cautious to make the generalization that you can omit any subject and verb in all cases, but for the most part people will intuit what the omitted subject is if the following sentence is reusing it.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!